# Is my professor allowed to change the day the class meets and mark us absent if we don't show?

Tags: professorship

I have a Wednesday Friday gym class that meets at 7 am. Lately the professor has been changing the class to meeting on Mondays instead of Wednesdays because she has stuff come up on Wednesdays. I don't think this is allowed but nobody else seems bothered by it. If you don't show up to the class you get an absent which takes points off your grade, the only way you get out of this is if you have proof that you have class or work. One time she changed the class to Monday instead of Friday, she didn't tell us this until the Sunday before at 11 am. She then marked the people who didn't show up absent when that is not enough time to tell a class to meet. Is this allowed? I feel like it shouldn't be allowed since class is on the days aloted, even when a school changes class days (I.e Wednesdays become Thursday classes) they aren't allowed to mark you as absent so why should my professor be allowed to? Please let me know what you guys think, thank you.

Comment: Have you (or your classmates) spoken to the professor about these concerns?  If so, what was her response?

Comment: Whether it's "allowed" is a question of your institution's regulations, and there's no way for me to know what those are.

Comment: I agree with Nate.  My *expectation* is that this would not be allowed without approval from a dean, or this time already being allotted for the course, but we'd need to know the relevant policies.  You can perhaps raise these questions to the instructor's supervisor (department chair).  Just do so in a non-aggressive fashion.  Be inquiring, not demanding/judgmental.

Answer (score 3):

Policies regarding what an instructor can, and cannot do, in a course tend to vary largely by institution, and even by department. It sounds to me like your best course of action is to politely raise your concerns to your professor, and see how she responds. It's possible that she's not aware of how her policies are inconveniencing her students, and if you explain why the policy is making it difficult for you to succeed and get the most out of the course, she may adjust accordingly. Note that if multiple students are being inconvenienced by this, it may be a good idea to discuss your concerns with the professor *together* (note that I didn't say you should tell the professor that other students agree with you, but rather that you should raise your concerns to her *with* your peers).

If you feel as though your concerns are not being heeded, then you may have to just deal with it as best you can until the semester ends. In my experience, professors tend to have a great deal of liberty in how they administer their policies, and there typically isn't much a student can do to challenge them. If it really becomes a problem, you could always discuss (again, politely) your concerns with your advisor, the department chair, or your school's ombudsman.